# Additional image sizes are not being generated

Tags: php, images, thumbnails

When I upload an image through the admin interface, the image is only saved at full-size. The other sizes are configured to their default values in Settings > Media. The automatic resized versions are not being generated. I have a feeling this is due to not having a specific PHP extension installed/enabled, but I don't know what extension WordPress uses or how to install/enable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be avoiding php-gd altogether as I couldn't get it installed. Instead, I installed the [ImageMagick Engine](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/imagemagick-engine/) WordPress plugin as well as ImageMagick on the server. Then I regenerated image sizes using the plugin to create the additional sizes for images I had already uploaded.

I posted the solution on my blog if you want more detail.
https://raddevon.com/articles/wordpress-image-resizing-without-php-gd/

Comment: Blog link broken

Comment: Link only answers are not appreciated in here, I guess... Please provide the solution in your answer...

Answer (score 2):

From https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/06/wp_image_editor-is-incoming/ :

> Imagick support requires Imagick 2.2.0+ compiled against Imagemagick 6.2.9+, for full support. If the required functions aren’t available, WordPress will default back to GD.

If you can, create a PHP file somewhere on your server with this content:  `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.  Then load the page and see if there is a section for either `imagick` or `gd`.

From mine:

```
gd
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible) 
etc.
```

(It's probably best if you delete or disable your `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` file afterwards, as it may supply plenty of valuable information to potential attackers.)

Comment: Neither of them appear to be installed. I've tried installing both of them, but I obviously don't know what I'm doing. `yum install php-gd` always fails because I have a newer version of one of the dependencies. I think I successfully installed ImageMagick, but I don't know how to enable it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience with `yum`. You might have to ask around on http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com/ or somewhere like that.

Comment: I found a solution to this. I'm writing up a blog post about my solution, and I'll be back here to post the answer after I collect my thoughts and write that up.

Comment: For ubuntu I had to do: `sudo apt-get install imagemagick php5-gd` and then restart the web server